# Graceful shutdown on SIGINT

Tags: c++, boost, signals, boost-asio

I would like to handle SIGINT signal from the kernel in order to call a function that grecefully shutdown my process.
Here's a working example, a thread is waiting the signal and then call the function handle_stop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void handle_stop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
    std::cout<<"Executing Safe Shutdown"<<std::cout;
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Init"<<std::cout;
    boost::asio::io_service signalService;
    boost::asio::signal_set signals(signalService, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT);
    signals.async_wait(handle_stop);
    boost::thread signalThread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &signalService));

    std::cout<<"Starting programm"<<std::cout;
    while (true) {
        std::cout<<"Waiting ctl-c"<<std::cout;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

My goal is pack inside a class the thread and the function to call for shut the process down.
Here's an non working attempt, **the process shutdown immediately without wait for the signal**.
What is wrong?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Shutdown {
public:
      Shutdown():is_signal_received_ (false) {
              //signals_::remove();
              std::cout<<"constructor"<<std::endl;
      }
      ~Shutdown() {
      }

      void init() {
              std::cout<<"Init "<<std::endl;
              boost::asio::signal_set signals(signalService_, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT);
              signals.async_wait(boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Shutdown::handleStop), this, _1, _2));
              boost::thread signalThread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &signalService_));
              std::cout<<"Init Completed"<<std::endl;
      }

      bool isSignalReceived() const {
              return is_signal_received_;
      }

private:
      std::atomic<bool> is_signal_received_;
      boost::asio::io_service signalService_;

      void handleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
              is_signal_received_ = true;
              myHandleStop(error, signal_number);
      }

      virtual void myHandleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
      }
};

class MyShutdown: public Shutdown {
private:
      void myHandleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
              std::cout<<"Executing Safe Shutdown"<<std::cout;
              exit(0);
      }
};

int main() {
    MyShutdown safeShutdown;
    safeShutdown.init();
    while (true) {
        std::cout<<"Waiting ctl-c"<<std::cout;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Here's the command for compiling:

> g++ -o main main.cpp -lpthread -l boost_thread -l boost_system --std=c++11

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `signal_set` goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of `Shutdown::init`.  When that happens, the `async_wait` is cancelled.  `signalThread` also goes out of scope at the same time without being either `detach`ed or `join`ed.  Those both need to be class members so that they stay alive until a signal can be handled:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Shutdown {
public:
    Shutdown()
        : is_signal_received_ (false),
        signalService_(),
        signals_(signalService_, SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT)
    {
        std::cout<<"constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~Shutdown()
    {
        signals_.cancel();
        signalService_.stop();
        signalThread_.join();
    }

    void init() {
        std::cout<<"Init "<<std::endl;
        signals_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Shutdown::handleStop, this, _1, _2));
        signalThread_ = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &signalService_));
        std::cout<<"Init Completed"<<std::endl;
    }

    bool isSignalReceived() const {
        return is_signal_received_;
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> is_signal_received_;
    boost::asio::io_service signalService_;
    boost::thread signalThread_;
    boost::asio::signal_set signals_;

    void handleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
        is_signal_received_ = true;
        myHandleStop(error, signal_number);
    }

    virtual void myHandleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
    }
};

class MyShutdown: public Shutdown {
private:
    void myHandleStop(const boost::system::error_code& error, int signal_number) {
        std::cout<<"Executing Safe Shutdown"<<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
};

int main() {
    MyShutdown safeShutdown;
    safeShutdown.init();
    while (true) {
        std::cout<<"Waiting ctl-c"<<std::endl;
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

I've also added calls to shut down the `io_service` and `signal_set` and to wait for the `thread` to terminate in `~Shutdown`.